# Work done on cylinder of nonuniform density rolling on hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I am trying to find the work done on a cylinder rolling (without slipping) down a hemisphere by a constant horizontal force $F$ applied on the cylinder. A diagram of this problem is presented below:

[image]

The cylinder has a non-uniform density defined by $\rho(r) = \frac{c}{L}(r^{2} + r)$, where $L$ is the length of the cylinder and $r$ is the distance of a point inside the cylinder to its axis of rotation, which goes through the geometric center of the cylinder. Would I be right to say that the units of $c$ are $\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{m}^{4}}$? Anyways, the horizontal force $F$ is applied to the cylinder by a person pointing towards its geometric center, which doesn't cause a torque initially since the force goes through the axis of rotation. However, static friction provides the torque for it to initially move, but there is no static friction force acting on it during movement since, well, it's moving. The cylinder experiences no kinetic friction during its rolling motion. The horizontal force acts a torque on the cylinder after the initial moment where the cylinder is on the top most point of the hemisphere. However, there is a certain point where a horizontal force can no longer be applied on the cylinder (in the direction of motion of the cylinder, that is). Once the topmost set of points of the cylinder is at the same height as the top most point of the hemisphere, the force is no longer applied (a human can't continue applying a force after that point since the hemisphere will get in the way). I am pretty sure that at that point, the force would be applied at the top most point of the cylinder above the geometric center.

The angle between the initial and final positions where the force is applied is $\arccos(\frac{R_{1}-R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}})$, where $R_{1}$ is the radius of the hemisphere and $R_{2}$ is the radius of the cylinder. By calculating the moment of inertia and the total mass of the cylinder, one derives that the moment of inertia of the non-uniform cylinder about its axis of rotation is $\frac{22}{35}MR_{2}^{2}$, where $M$ is the total mass of the cylinder. Calculating the center of mass of the cylinder surprisingly leads to the conclusion that the center of mass of the cylinder ($\; (0,0,\frac{L}{2})$ in Cartesian coordinates ) is also the location of the geometric center of the cylinder, despite the density of the cylinder being non-uniform. Since the center of mass is located at the geometric center of the cylinder, and is, therefore, also on the axis of rotation, this means that the gravitational force nor the normal force exerts a torque on the cylinder throughout its movement, which means the the only force producing a torque between the initial and final times is the force $F$ exerted. I wish to find an expression for $F$ in order to evaluate the integral expression for work:

$$\int_{0}^{\arccos(\frac{R_{1}-R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}})} F\cos(\theta) d\theta$$

To find $F$, I feel as through you would have to solve the following system of equations:

$$\sum F_{c} = \frac{Mv^{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}} = M\omega ^{2}(R_{1}+R_{2})$$
$$\sum F_{t} = M\alpha (R_{1}+R_{2}) $$
$$\sum \tau  = \frac{22}{35}MR_{2}^{2}\alpha$$

Where $F_{c}$ represents the centripetal forces, $F_{t}$ represents the tangential forces, $\omega$ is angular velocity, $\alpha$ is angular acceleration, and $\tau$ represents torque. The factor of $(R_{1}+R_{2})$ is presented in the force equations since the the motion of the center of mass should be of concern when discussing the motion of the rigid body. There are two issues that I have with this. The first one is that I'm not sure how to set up the force equations, since involves a complicated free body diagram instead of a force diagram. The second one is that the angle at which the force $F$ exerts a torque on the cylinder changes during the motion, so I need to find a function for how that angle changes (thankfully, the force is still always applied at a distance of $R_{2}$ away from the axis of rotation). I think that, other than the initial position, the angle at which the force applies a torque on the cylinder is proportional to the angular displacement of the cylinder from the initial position. So if the angle at which the force applies a torque on the cylinder at time $t\neq0$ during the time the force is applied is $\beta$, and if the angular displacement from the initial position at that time is $\theta$, then

$$\frac{\beta}{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{\theta}{\arccos(\frac{R_{1}-R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}})}$$

since the angle at which the torque is applied at the final position is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. If this is not right, which I'm not sure it is, then I don't know how to find the work exerted by force $F$ while it is applied in this situation.

Comment: Please note that questions which ask for help or feedback with solving a problem or exercise are *off topic* for this site. If you have a conceptual difficulty which is hampering you please focus on that.

Comment: Would this be more appropriate to ask in Math Stack Exchange? Because I already laid some ground work to show how I would solve the problem, but I am not sure how to continue with it.

Comment: No I think the question would be closed on Mathematics SE because it is a question about physics. Recommendations for sites where you might get help are given in https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh. Provided that you have a reputation of 20 points or more you can ask for help in [Problem Solving Strategies chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies).